# How to send Json type of input in the post method

Tags: asp.net-web-api

i have a set of rest APIs services.am creating a proxy layer above the rest API service.It has login method with POST format and it accepts input in the form of json.I created a proxy layer and am sending the user namenpassword from URL to the Rest service.I created an entity for login which has 2 properties.[user name & password]

Here is the Code:

```
public void Login([FromUri] string userName, [FromUri]string password)
        {
            string jsonParams = string.Empty;
            LoginData obj = new LoginData();
            obj.username = userName;
            obj.password = password;
            jsonParams = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

            string LoginUrl = "http://restservice/account/login/"
            var result = Utils.SendGETRequest(LoginUrl, jsonParams);
}
```

above code works fine.once login is successful,It wil return a messgae as "success".My question is how to convert the above method into POST because i don't want to send username,password using url.I just want to know how to send JSON type of input.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx), probably most specifically a [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx).  That way you can let the System package do most of the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. This allows you to send http posts using the
`httpClient.PostAsync(url, content)` method. As it's an asynchronous method you can also utilise the new [async](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) features in C# 5.